# SQL0526N when referencing a DGTT (Declared global temporary table) in a FUNCTION

Tags: db2, db2-luw, sql-pl

I would like to return content from a pre-created DGTT as a result-set for a table function.

But when I reference it,  I get SQL SQL0526N / SQLSTATE   42995 error.

I can't see why.  [Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-declare-global-temporary-table) says only 3 reasons for 42995 sqlstate error:

```
Restrictions on the use of declared temporary tables: Declared temporary tables cannot:
- Be specified in an ALTER, COMMENT, GRANT, LOCK, RENAME or REVOKE statement (SQLSTATE 42995).
- Be referenced in an AUDIT, CREATE ALIAS, or CREATE VIEW statement (SQLSTATE 42995).
- Be specified in referential constraints (SQLSTATE 42995).
```

But none of them are being used..  The function is pretty simple:

```
BEGIN  ATOMIC 

    CALL DBAREP.SP_ROW_CHECKSUM(sSchema, sTable, sColumnList, sWhere, iRows) ;     

    RETURN 
         (SELECT * FROM SESSION.DBAREP_ROW_CHECKSUM ) ;
END@
```

What rule am I violating this time?

Comment: The docs do state that inlined functions (compound SQL inlined) cannot use dynamic SQL features, which to  me excludes DGTT use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not explicitly stated in docs, but `Declared` GTTs can't be used in inlined compound statements (with BEGIN ATOMIC ... END).
You may use `Created` GTT in an inlined compound statement instead.

Comment: Thanks @Mark. hope the doc could be more clear on this...